# Is it possible to use CUDA 10.2 with tensorflow 2.1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am finding problems with installing CUDA 10.1 because of the incompatibility with my graphic card (GeForce RTX 2060). I successfully installed CUDA 10.2. But it looks incompatible with Tensorflow 2.1.

When I run this code on python:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices()
```

it returns an empty list, meaning that there are no available GPUs.

Is there a way to solve this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this stream https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34759, tensorflow 2.1 is not working with cuda 10.2 unless you build from the sources.

The only way to easily solve your problem is to downgrade to Cuda 10.1, unless you want to build from source.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to install Cuda 10.1 Update 2 and now it works perfectly :)

Comment: Yes, sure. Done :)